# Mouse wont respond to small movements

Tags: windows, mouse, synaptics-touchpad

I just bought a new laptop, and like most, it comes with a Synaptics Driver. When I make very small and short movements with the mouse, the mouse flicks back to where it started to. 
[image]

Is there any known fix/explanation? I had a very difficult time looking for a solution online.

Comment: Could be hardware. As its new take it back to shop

Comment: I'm not sure about that because it detects the movement, it just snaps it back

Comment: Try increasing sensitivity and disable palm rejection.

Comment: @RadialApps I have disables palm rejection completely and increased sensitivity to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, the steelseries engine app suggests to to disable "Enhance pointer precision" in the mouse properties.

The drawback will be a noticeable difficulty in moving the mouse from one side of the screen to the opposite.